# Fetching logical disk serial number for offline disk

Tags: windows, powershell

can we fetch logical disk serial number for offline disks? or will the logical disk number will be avalible only for the online disks.

searched on google,nothing crisp info on offline disks.thats why posting in stackoverflow

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can. Use the get-Wmiobject to fetch it from Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition and Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition class

Answer (score 0):

Try this also:

```
Get-WMIObject -class win32_PhysicalMedia | Select SerialNumber
```

Note: SerialNumber is optional and should be provided by the driver

Comment: Through this command, i am getting junk values through this command for offline disks and valid serial numbers for online disks. just for FYI why the above command results in different results when we run the command multiple times.

Comment: i have 8 disks.

Comment: so what it is resulting? in that case you need to wrap it in foreach loop by taking all the disks